# ScrollView didn't adjust when the Keyboard is open

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

I created an activity with a form in it. Because the form is quite long,so I've used a scrollview.The problem is that, the scrollview doesn't change when the keyboard is up. The keyboard overlaps the last part of the scrollview.

i've used min Sdk of 16 target of 25.

i've been struggling in this problem could anyone could help me out of this, thanks in advance.

Here is the problem in this image
[image]

I want to be like this (EDITED PIC) 
[image]

i've been trying to change the manifest using this code:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

and this code in my activity

```
context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Here is the Full XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_create_new_user"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingTop="22dp"
    android:scrollbarSize="20dp"
    tools:context="com.jlmaychinny.app.cashbilis.Ui_Activities.CreateNewUserActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Create your account by providing the following."
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <com.jlmaychinny.app.cashbilis.CircleImageView.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/createnewuser_profile_image"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/person_icon"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:civ_border_width="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createnewuser_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_design"
            android:hint="Juan Dela Cruz"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="State:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createnewuser_address_state"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_design"
            android:hint="Davao Del Sur"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createnewuser_address_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_design"
            android:hint="Davao City"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home Address:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createnewuser_address_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_design"
            android:hint="Blk.16 Pag-asa st.,Brgy. Forever"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createnewuser_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_design"
            android:hint="cashBilis@CashBilis.com"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:text="Password:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/createnewuser_show_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createnewuser_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_design"
            android:hint="************"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createnewuser_password_confirm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_design"
            android:hint="Confirm your password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/createnewuser_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="CREATE USER"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try   `android:fillViewport="true"`  in scrollView.

Comment: same result. it didn't fix the problem

Comment: can you post your full xml code?so that i can check issue .

Comment: sure! if it could be a help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in mainfiest file inside your activity
and use in tour xml inside edittext use 
  android:singleLine="true"

Comment: thanks! but still the button hides at the back of the keyboard keyboard

Comment: you can use action on edit text   use     android:imeOptions="actionDone"

Comment: keybord will hide after click done button in androoid

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to you maintain both the "adjustResize|adjustPan".

Just remove the adjustPan From your Androidmainfest.xml 
(ex:android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize")
and also Remove context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE); from your java file.

I think it will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using **`addOnLayoutChangeListener`** on your **scrollView** as following:

```java
scrollView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                if (bottom < oldBottom) {
                    scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                        }
                    }, 100);
                }
            }
        });
```